# Laravel: Poner condición dentro de una llamada de Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, laravel-5

Primero voy a poner el codigo que tengo.

Este es mi código Javascript:

```
//View para crear proyecto
$("#myFormProject").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  $.ajax({
    url:'/admin/projects/postUpload',
    type:'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function() {
      $("#formcrearproyecto").fadeOut(1000);
      $("#formcreartraducciones").fadeIn(1000);
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });
  return false;
});
```

Y esta es la función del controlador que ejecuta:

```
public function storeProject(Request $request) {
    $clients = DB::table('clients')->orderBy('name','asc')->get();
    $projects = DB::table('projects')->get();
    $project = new Project();
    $project->slug = $request->input("slug");
    $project->order = DB::table('projects')
        ->where('order', DB::raw("(select max(`order`) from projects)"))
        ->first()
        ->order + 1; 
    $project->public = 0;
    $imagen = getimagesize($request->file('pathheader'));
    $ancho = $imagen[0];
    $altura = $imagen[1];
    $maxancho = 1930;
    $minancho = 1910;
    $maxaltura = 822;
    $minaltura = 802;
    $imagen2 = getimagesize($request->file('pathhome'));
    $ancho2 = $imagen2[0];
    $altura2 = $imagen2[1];
    $maxancho2 = 778;
    $minancho2 = 358;
    $maxaltura2 = 355;
    $minaltura2 = 335;
    if ($ancho < $maxancho && $ancho > $minancho && $altura < $maxaltura && $altura > $minaltura && $ancho2 < $maxancho2 && $ancho2 > $minancho2 && $altura2 < $maxaltura2 && $altura2 > $minaltura2) {
        \Storage::disk('projects')->makeDirectory($project->slug);
        $project->pathheader = \Storage::disk('projects')-> putFileAs($project->slug, $request->file('pathheader'),'header.jpg');
        $project->pathhome = \Storage::disk('projects')->putFileAs($project->slug, $request->file('pathhome'),'home.jpg');
        $project->save();
        File::put(resource_path('views/projects/').$project->slug.'.blade.php','');
    } else {
        Session::flash('warning','Las medidas de almenos una de las 2 imagenes no es la correcta.');
        return view('cms.public.views.projects.menu',['projects' => $projects, 'clients' => $clients]);
    }
 }
```

El problema es que cuando pasa al else que hay un Session::flash, como oculta el div por ajax y muestra el otro div no se ve. La idea es que directamente no pase de vista, que haga un refresh en la misma página y muestre el session::flash.

Como seria posible hacer esto?

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Lo que quería era chequear si entraba en el if o no y que el cliente viera una cosa u otra. Gracias igualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

```
// codigo
if($ancho2<$maxancho2 && $ancho2>$minancho2 && $altura2<$maxaltura2 && $altura2>$minaltura2)
{
  // codigo
   ......

   $project->save();
   File::put(resource_path('views/projects/').$project->slug.'.blade.php','');
   // devolvemos el json al cliente
   return json_encode(['stauts'=>'ok']);
}
else{
     $data = array('status' => 'error',
                   'warning' => 'Las medidas de almenos una de las 2 imagenes no es la correcta.');
      return json_encode($data);
```

Ahora chequeamos en la llamada de ajax el estado de la petición.

```
$("#myFormProject").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
       url:'/admin/projects/postUpload',
       type:'POST',
       data: formData,
       success: function(responseText){
            // convierte el string json a un objeto json 
            $responseData = JSON.parse(responseText);
            if($responseData.status == 'ok')
            {
                 $("#formcrearproyecto").fadeOut(1000);
                 $("#formcreartraducciones").fadeIn(1000);
            }
            else if($responseData.status == 'error'){
                  alert($responseData.warning);
             }
            else{
                alert('Error happened in backend,but not handled');
            }
       },
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false;
});
```